# Inject custom class into subclass inheritance tree in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I think of myself as an experienced Objective-C programmer. I do apps for a living, and use the language features to it's fullest. That includes using the runtime for varies just-in-time changes to existing frameworks. Stuff like method swizzling and dynamic subclassing really shows how this language is so much more versatile than it's other object oriented C counterpart.

But lately I've been having some thoughts about an old feature, that I still find myself in need of using from time to time, but has been deprecated for some time now. It's a replacement for the old `class_setSuperClass`.

I often find myself subclassing UIKit classes in order to extend them or just change their behaviour slightly. One example I came across recently was an `UIScrollView` subclass, that made some conditions to the `panGestureRecognizer`. I did that by subclassing `UIScrollView` and then implementing the `gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:`.

This had to be done this way, because you're not allowed to change the delegate of a scroll view's pan gesture recogniser (it will throw a runtime exception), and you cannot create your own custom UIScrollView `panGestureRecognizer`.

Now this all worked out great. I changed all usages of `UIScrollView` in my app to my newly created subclass, and everything worked as expected. But what about `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` which I also used throughout the app. What to do with those? As you know, both of these classes is inherited from `UIScrollView`, but not my custom subclass of `UIScrollView`. So I found myself ending up writing *the same code multiple times* for every class that existed (and was used in the app) that inherited from `UIScrollView`. Writing the same code multiple times is a programmers 1-2-3 no-go. But I did end up writing a custom subclass not only for `UIScrollView` but also for `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`.

Now in the old days with the `class_setSuperClass` you were able to *"swizzle"* the superclass of an already prepackaged class like `UITableView`. You basically just said `class_setSuperClass([UITableView class], [MyScrollView class])`, and everything worked out (well almost) fine. Now you had injected your own class in between `UITableView` and `UIScrollView`. So every time you did `[[UITableView alloc] init]` it would have the features of `MyScrollView` because it inherited directly from it.

Now `class_setSuperClass` was deprecated in iOS 2.0! Since that we could do some swizzling and hacking with the object's `isa` pointer. Now that has been deprecated too.

So my question is really simple. How would you approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to globally change a class's behavior, rather than play with class identities, the direct approach would just be to replace the method you want replaced. The runtime still allows this, with `class_replaceMethod()`. That seems like the simplest way to accomplish what you want here.

Comment: Yes I agree. And now that you mention it, I can't see why I just didn't make it that way. But what about if this was some complex subclass with lots of overridden methods? Wouldn't that approach end up a little messy?

Comment: @Trenskow: I don't see how it would get particularly messy. You might need to do a little more for more complex cases (e.g. create a backup of the original method to call to if you need `super`-like behavior), but it's not really explosive complexity or anything. Do you have something in particular in mind?

Comment: You get a correct answer. I think this is the best solution as things are right now. :)